# Left and right product with a PD diagonal can be expressed as a PD quadratic form?

Tags: linear-algebra

I conjecture the following: If $D$ is diagonal, $D \succeq I$, and $V$ has linearly independent columns,
then there exists $R \succeq I$ such that
$$
 V^T R V
 =
 D V^T V D.
$$
I can prove the theorem when $V$ is square. For the case where V is "tall", I have tested this numerically with randomly chosen values of $V$ and $D$.
The numerical solution performs a linear least-squares solve of
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\Vec}{Vec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
 (V^T \otimes V^T) \Vec(R)
 =
 \Vec(D V^T V D)
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product.
This is equivalent to solving for $R$ in the equality stated in the conjecture.
I check that the solution satisfies $\Vec^{-1}(R) \succeq I$ up to a numerical tolerance.

It is true that
$$
\rank(A \otimes B) = \rank(A) \rank(B),
$$
so we can assert that the solution $\Vec(R)$ exists,
but proving that $R \succeq I$ seems harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Consider $V=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}$ and $D=\pmatrix{1\\ &2}$. Then
$$
R=(V^T)^{-1}DV^TVDV^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&5}
$$
and clearly $R-I$ is indefinite.